# Incorrect data redirects user to a blank page from a Servlet Login page

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, authentication

In my project a user logs in by providing his/her `emailid` and `password`. If both match, one can successfully log-in. If not he will be redirected to `UserHome.jsp` page. Here is my code:

```
import getset.Getset;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import accessdb.Dao;

public class LoginAuthentication extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // Authentication and Logging in The Registered User
        Getset g=new Getset();
        Dao dao=new Dao();
        String userid="";
        String fname="";
        //    PrintWriter pw=response.getWriter();
        String loginemail=request.getParameter("loginemail");
        String loginpassword=request.getParameter("loginpassword");
        if (loginemail.equals("") || 
            loginemail.equals(" ") || 
            loginpassword.equals("") || 
            loginpassword.equals(" "))

            response.sendRedirect("WelcomePage.jsp");

        g.setloginemail(loginemail);
        g.setloginpassword(loginpassword);
        try {
            ResultSet rs=dao.loginauthentication(g);
            while(rs.next())
            {
                String regemail=rs.getString("regemail");
                String regpassword=rs.getString("regpassword");
                if(loginemail.equals(regemail) && 
                   (loginpassword.equals(regpassword))==true)
                {
                    ResultSet rs1=dao.getnameid(g);
                    while(rs1.next())
                    {
                         userid=rs1.getString("USERID");
                         fname=rs1.getString("FNAME");
                    }
                    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
                    session.setAttribute("USERID", userid);
                    session.setAttribute("FNAME", fname);
                    response.sendRedirect("UserHome.jsp");
                    break;
                }
                else if(loginemail.equals(regemail) && (loginpassword.equals(regpassword))==false)
                {
                    response.sendRedirect("WelcomePage.jsp");
                    return;
                }
            }
        } 
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to cover all the cases that may arise during log-in. The user can not access if

1. both the fields remain empty.
2. `email` is filled (with correct or incorrect data), but `password` is not filled.
3. `password` is filled (with correct or incorrect data), but `emailid` is not filled.

The area which I tried to cover, but is not happening, is don't let a user access if any of the fields are filled with incorrect data. For this part I have written in the code:

```
 if(loginemail.equals(regemail) && (loginpassword.equals(regpassword))==true)
     //user accesses
 else 
     if(loginemail.equals(regemail) && (loginpassword.equals(regpassword))==false)
         //user cannot access
```

But I don't know why it's not showing the expected behaviour and when both the fields are filled with incorrect data, user is **redirected** to a blank page!

**Addition:** I also tried

```
if(loginemail.equals(regemail) && (loginpassword.equals(regpassword)))
   //User accesses
 else if(!loginemail.equals(regemail) || (!loginpassword.equals(regpassword)))
  //User cannot access
```

But it too could not help!

Comment: You mentioned : "don't let a user access if both the fields are filled with incorrect data". Ideally, you should not allow login if either email or password is incorrect

Comment: @Hardik Mishra you are correct. I am going to change the code accordingly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After a long try, I finally got my working code. And here it is:

```
import getset.Getset;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import accessdb.Dao;

public class LoginAuthentication extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // Authentication and Logging in The Registered User
    Getset g=new Getset();
    Dao dao=new Dao();
    String userid="";
    String fname="";
//  PrintWriter pw=response.getWriter();
    String loginemail=request.getParameter("loginemail");
    String loginpassword=request.getParameter("loginpassword");
    if(loginemail.equals("")||loginemail.equals(" ")||loginpassword.equals("")||loginpassword.equals(" "))
    {
        response.sendRedirect("WelcomePage.jsp");
    }
    else{
    g.setloginemail(loginemail);
    g.setloginpassword(loginpassword);
    try {
        ResultSet rs=dao.loginauthentication(g);
        while(rs.next())   //Fetching all emails and passwords from user table
        {
            String regemail=rs.getString("regemail");
            String regpassword=rs.getString("regpassword");
            System.out.println(""+regemail);
            if(loginemail.equals(regemail) && (loginpassword.equals(regpassword)))
            {   
                System.out.println("55555");
                ResultSet rs1=dao.getnameid(g);
                while(rs1.next())   //GET USERID and name FROM NEWUSER TO USE AS PRIMARY KEY
                {
                     userid=rs1.getString("USERID");
                     fname=rs1.getString("FNAME");
                    System.out.println(""+userid);

                }

                HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
                  session.setAttribute("USERID", userid);
                  session.setAttribute("FNAME", fname);
                response.sendRedirect("UserHome.jsp");
                break;
            }

        }

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
}
}
```

Thanks everyone, who tried to help me!!

Comment: Are you sure that it works on incorrect email and password ? If it deos I am surprised

Comment: @HardikMishra Yes. Its fully working. But why are you surprised? Is there anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple

```
else
```

instead of

```
else if(loginemail.equals(regemail) && (loginpassword.equals(regpassword))==false)
```

Also, please check [the Java operator precedence information](http://bmanolov.free.fr/javaoperators.php).

As, you have `loginemail.equals(regemail) && (loginpassword.equals(regpassword))==false`, which seems to be treated as: `false && false == false` - which will return false.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a blank page. It means none of the `if` conditions in your code is executing to redirect to a page.

I didn't get what you are trying to achieve. Ideally, you should have only two conditions:

1. Redirect to UsersHome on both email and password correct.
2. Redirect to the welcome page if either one is incorrect.

Code snippet:

```
// Servlet instance variable
String redirectPage = "WelcomePage.jsp";
```

Change

```
if(loginemail.equals("")||loginemail.equals(" ")||loginpassword.equals("")||loginpassword.equals(" "))
        response.sendRedirect("WelcomePage.jsp");
```

to

```
    if(loginemail.equals("")||loginemail.equals(" ")||loginpassword.equals("")||loginpassword.equals(" "))
         redirectMyPage(response);
    // There should be only one record. So, If should be used.
    if(rs.next()) {
        //In my opinion there is no need of this. But you haven't mentioned your DAO part.
        // You should write DAO in such manner that if both email and password are correct, then
        // only return a record from the database.
        if(loginemail.equals(regemail) && (loginpassword.equals(regpassword))==true)
        {
            //Your other code ...
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
            session.setAttribute("USERID", userid);
            session.setAttribute("FNAME", fname);
            redirectPage = UserHome.jsp";
        }
        // No need of else
    }
    redirectMyPage(response);
    //.. Other code
}

private void redirectMyPage(HttpResponse response){
    response.sendRedirect(redirectPage);
    return;
}
```

Comment: That's true. I also want to achieve, if any field is empty, user will be redirected to Welcome Page.

Comment: @SubirAdhikari: Check edited answer. Dpn't copy paste all. Its snippet, adjust it in your code.

Comment: okay.Giving it a try.Just wanted to know what is the facility of creating `redirectMyPage` extra?

Comment: @SubirAdhikari: Try debugging code. I just gave an idea. I didn't try

Comment: I tried. Maybe there is some logical deficiency which should be introduced.